# Injecting function with initializer in ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have an app built on Ember-cli. I am trying to inject a method into all routes, controllers, and views. I am aware I could utilize the `app/utils` directory and import the method's module into all the files that call it, but I would like the method to be automatically available. Hence, I have chosen to inject the method using an initializer.

The initializer looks like this:

```
export default {
  name: 'injectMethod',

  initialize: function(container, app) {
    var someFunction = function(message) {

    };

    app.register('function:main', someFunction);

    Em.A(['route', 'controller', 'view']).forEach(function(place) {
      app.inject(place, 'someFunction', 'function:main');
    });
  }
};
```

This results in the following error message: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`. The error disappears when I remove the `app.inject()` line.

Are initializers handled differently in ember-cli and/or is something in the above code incorrect? Or is they a better way to achieve my goal than using an initializer?

Comment: donno how ember-cli works yet..but here does app available globally?

Comment: One of the goals of ember-cli/es6 modules is to remove everything from global namespaces. `App` isn't available globally because you're registering individual modules.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ember expects you to register a factory which it can create instances using the `create` method.  If you are passing in an instance (or just a method) you would need to tell Ember not to attempt to instantiate it and just use the instance passed in.

```
export default {
  name: 'injectMethod',

  initialize: function(container, app) {
    var someFunction = function(message) {

    };

    app.register('function:main', someFunction, {instantiate: false});

    Em.A(['route', 'controller', 'view']).forEach(function(place) {
      app.inject(place, 'someFunction', 'function:main');
    });
  }
};
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xaboliwu/1/edit

Comment: There's also a nice detailed blog post about this at http://balinterdi.com/2014/05/01/dependency-injection-in-ember-dot-js.html